# Show that $(\int_{X} g^{-1} d\mu)(\int_{X} g d\mu) \geq 1$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space such that $\mu X = 1$, and let $g:
> X \rightarrow (0,1)$.
>
> Show that: $\displaystyle\left(\int_{X} g^{-1} d\mu\right)\displaystyle\left(\int_{X} g d\mu\right) \geq 1$

**My Attempt**

Let $\phi(x) = \displaystyle \frac{1}{x}$ be a convex function at $x \in (0,1)$ thus by Jensen's Inequality we have:

$\displaystyle\phi\left(\int_{X} g d\mu\right) \leq \int_{X}\left(\phi\circ g\right) d\mu$

$\Rightarrow$ $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\displaystyle\int_{X} g d\mu} \leq\int_{X} \frac{1}{g} d\mu$

$\Rightarrow 1 \leq \displaystyle\left(\int_{X} g^{-1} d\mu\right)\left(\int_{X}{g}d\mu\right)$

Now i think there's a problem with my proof.

First, do I need to show $\phi$ is convex? if so I can show a graphical approach to show that it is convex but I can't show it by using a definition. Lastly, I'm having a problem with the function $g$ if it is in $L^{1}$? Any help will do.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: What if $g(x) = x$ and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: It would be less ambiguous if you used ${1 \over g}$ rather than $g^{-1}$ which is often used for the inverse function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that $g$ is measurable so that the integrals make sense.

The inequality is true whether or not the integrals are finite. If one of the integrals is infinity then  the product is $\infty$ (since the other one cannot be $0$) so the  inequality is true. When both the integrals are finite your proof works since Jensen's inequality is applicable.

Convexity of $\frac 1 x$ follows from the fact that its second derivative is non-negative.

Comment: Seems like the second derivative is really intuitive to show rather than using it graphically. Thank you.

Comment: I do have another question. Is $g$ finite? if it is, how to show that g is finite?

Comment: It is given that $g$ takes values in $(0,1)$.  @Dencio